# yii url manager: set up a unique code

Tags: yii, url-routing

I want this format of url: http://example.com/c5e8fe2 to be pointing to a specific controller/action. The code in the url is unique for every model instance and should be sent as param to this controller/action. Its length is always 7 chars long. I tried this in my rules array, but unsuccessful:

```
'<code:\[a-z0-9]{7}>'=>'controller/action'
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'<code:([A-Za-z0-9-]{7})>'=>'controller/action'
```

This did the trick for me.